# Joining 2 tables with the same primary key SQL Server to C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

whats up guys, i have some trouble with this code i hope u guys can figured out

I have 2 Tables ( Customer & Registration ) Using SQL Server

Customer

> 1. Id
> 2. Name
> 3. etc

Registration

> 1. Id
> 2. Date

i working on my C# Program, i want to show them into a `listview` but i have error here is my code :

```
public void listdata()
    {
        SqlDataReader reader = null;

        listView1.Items.Clear();
        listView1.Columns.Clear();
        listView1.Columns.Add("ID", 55, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Tanggal Registrasi", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Nama Pemohon", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Center);

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = konn.GetConn();
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            string sql = "select*from Ms_Register a join Ms_Coba b on a.id = b.id where id='" + textBox1.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn); 
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

            //Check
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();


            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ListViewItem item1 = new     ListViewItem(reader["id"].ToString(), 0);
                item1.SubItems.Add(reader["tanggal"].ToString());
                item1.SubItems.Add(reader["nama"].ToString());

                listView1.Items.Add(item1);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

    }
```

The both tables have same id and the error says "Ambiguous column name "id" "
anyone have the way to solve this ? Thank you

Comment: Looks like your both table have `id` column and reader confuse about _which_ `id` you want to get. Have you ever tried to get it with full db and column name? BTW, `select *` is _usually_ a bad idea.

Comment: you are filtering by Customer or Registration? Change this to either "where a.id='" or "where b.id='".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from Ms_Register a join Ms_Coba b on a.id = b.id where id='" + textBox1.Text + "'"
```

Should be either `WHERE a.id` or `WHERE b.id`, does not matter which **in this case since they are identical**

This is really bad code, though, you should be sanitizing textBox1's value by using parameters for your query.  Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: so did u think its impossible to grab data in the 2 table with the same id?

Comment: No, it is possible and the answer above is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your query was wrong, Change it as follows:

```
string sql = "select * from Ms_Register a join Ms_Coba b on a.id = b.id where a.id='" + textBox1.Text + "'";
```

Because both table contains field name as same, so we have to mention which table field to be choose on where clause

Comment: i use ur code and this is the answer : Execute reader requires an open and available connection. The connection current state is closed. whats wrong?

Comment: You've closed your connection after running command.ExecuteNonQuery() that is why the reader requires you to reopen the connection. It is better to close the connection after the while loop finished executing.